# how to stop telephone ringing when get call, but not mute it globally

Tags: android

I know how to mute sound globally when phone is ringing:

```
AudioManager audioManager = (AudioManager)context.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);                  
audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_SILENT);
```

but i would like to mute phone ringing without make it SILENT globally. Like if you click sound button on the phone and it stops ringing.

How would i do this programmatically?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Could you just mute on the ringer stream when the phone is in a state of ringing and then turn it back on once the ringing has finished. You can use a content observer to check on the current state of the phone. I think from ICS onwards that the ringtone and notification sounds are all played on the same stream I can't think of another way to do this. It does mean you'll get no sound on for notifications while the phone is ringing.

```
audioManager.setStreamMute(AudioManager.STREAM_RING, true);
```

Comment: thank you for your answer. So if i need sound in notification i can not mute just ringing from incoming call and play notification sound?

Comment: @Andrew: There's a separate stream type named STREAM_NOTIFICATION, which shouldn't be affected by muting STREAM_RING.

Comment: I'm pretty sure in ice cream sandwich and above that if you change the volume of the ringer the notification volume will also change. I think a few phones such as the s3 override this to gain two separate streams, but most don't.